# Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. while using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, nodemailer

I am getting error "Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted" while trying to send mail using nodejs.
I have double checked my email and password

**code: 'EAUTH',
response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'piyush212@gmail.com',
    pass: '***********'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'piyush212@gmail.com',
  to: '@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: ' hello world'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Mhhhh... there's probably some error somewhere in the code... I would start looking there

Comment: You should read the full document here: [https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/)